# Setup GMX email with SSMTP

Tags: email, ssmtp

I setup the simplest outgoing email server possible with `ssmtp`. It is giving me the error `Authorization failed (535 Authentication credentials invalid)`. Here is my configuration without comments:

```
# /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
root=myemail@gmx.com
mailhub=mail.gmx.com:465
rewriteDomain=gmx.com
hostname=HP-Q101
rewriteDomain=gmx.com
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=myemail@gmx.com
AuthPass=my@super&secret*pa$$word
UseTLS=YES
```

Running output:

```
~$ ssmtp -vvv webmaster@example.com < msg
[<-] 220 gmx.com (mrgmxus001) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
[->] EHLO ASUS-N53SM
[<-] 250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
[->] AUTH LOGIN
[<-] 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
[->] c3VwZXZvMZExZGdteZ3jb33=
[<-] 334 ZZFzc3dvcmZ3
[<-] 535 Authentication credentials invalid
ssmtp: Authorization failed (535 Authentication credentials invalid)
```

I understand that this implies a wrong username or password, but I have confirmed the password by copying it directly from my password manager. I also tried setting my user name to only `myemail`.

- Anyone have luck setting up a GMX account?
- If the problem isn't username/password, what could it possibly be?

Comment: Maybe you need STARTTLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your config to match this:

```
# /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
root=youremail@gmx.com
mailhub=mail.gmx.com:587
rewriteDomain=gmx.com
hostname=gmx.com
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=youremail@gmx.com
AuthPass=yourpassword
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

Source:
https://help.gmx.com/en/applications/pop3.html

Comment: Dead link. Also what's the point of having twice the `rewriteDomain` setting?

Comment: There is no point of having it twice. I have corrected the typo

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has still had this authentication problem even after the config file was changed to what Rucent88 proposed, the problem I had was with a complicated password for my GMX account, with special characters like punctuation, brackets, number sign, etc.

Maybe the parsing of the ssmtp.conf file isn't that great, anyway I changed it to something alphanumeric, and it worked.